# com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.key.CacheKeyGeneratorUtil.getCacheKeyGenerator

Tags: spring, junit, liferay

I try to create a Junit test, the probleme is that I get the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.key.CacheKeyGeneratorUtil.getCacheKeyGenerator(CacheKeyGeneratorUtil.java:56)
```

the program can't instantiate the the CacheKeyGenerator -cause the defaultCacheKeyGenerator is already null!! this latter can be instantiated when PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) is called... but I'm not using PortalContextLoaderListener ... is there any way to solve this probleme

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you're about to test, my advice is typically an additional level of indirection. If you need something that depends on larger infrastructure to be initialized, like in this case, it's not a proper unit test any more, rather a larger integration test.

Adding an indirection to get the cache-key should suffice. At runtime you can hook that component up to Liferay, at testing time, you return your testing values, that could be constants, random results or whatever you need for your test.